# Update multiple rows at once using Former in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a form that contains a list of settings, all with their own IDs, shown via simple foreach loop. When the user clicks the update button, I want to be able to update all of the values using Anahkiasen/Former. However, I can't seem to find the documentation on how to submit more than one set of records.

For instance, if I was opening the form to edit just one setting instead of all of them, I would just do the following:

```
{{ Former::open()->method('PUT')->action(URL::to('settings/' . $setting['id'])) }}
```

This would send it to my 'update' resource method and the following code would take care of the update:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $setting = Setting::findOrFail($id);

    if ($setting->save()) {
        return Redirect::back()->with('message', "Setting #$id updated!");
    } else {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($setting->errors());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this with multiple records at once and still use the convenient `$autoHydrateEntityFromInput` and `$forceEntityHydrationFromInput` features?

I'm using Laravel 4.1 and Former 3.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had to be done by just putting the values into an array and forcing the existing value in the Blade template:

```
@foreach ($settings as $s)
<div class="row">
    {{ Former::text('values[' . $s['id'] . ']', $s['name'])->forceValue($s['value']) }}
</div>
@endforeach
```

Then retrieve the values in the controller:

```
public function update()
{
    $values = Input::get('values');

    foreach ($values as $id => $val) {
        $setting = Setting::findOrFail($id);

        $setting['value'] = $val;

        if (!$setting->save()) {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($setting->errors());
        }
    }

    return Redirect::back()->with('message', "Settings updated!");
}
```

Doing it this way, a standard resource won't work like `Route::resource('settings', 'SettingsController');` so instead I had to simply do `Route::post('settings/update', 'SettingsController@update');`

As far as I can tell, auto hydration also won't work in this case.